# Creating database in other computer via code

Tags: c#, database

I want my application to create database in the user's computer. The database would be simple, with only one table. Is this possible? What would be in the connection string? Should the user have installed some kind of server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [SQL CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) - it is an embedded database which you can distribute with your application.

> Microsoft SQL Server Compact (SQL CE) is a compact relational database produced by Microsoft for applications that run on mobile devices and desktops.